# Access a file passing windows credentials in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Want to access files placed at specific location . Need to read that file by passing windows username, password, domain . I am working with Vb.net , framework 4 . Please guide and provide a sample example for the same

Comment: You should try something (Google?) first instead of asking for an example on SO.

Comment: I have tried only then i am posting for the example

Comment: Tell what you tried then.